# Instagram API Bad request

Tags: asp.net, instagram, instagram-api

I have a web application allowing users to login by their instagram account.
I've registered my app to Instagram.

When the user clicks the login button, I direct him to instagram page to login:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?scope=basic+relationships&client_id={MyClientId}&redirect_uri={My call back aspx page}&response_type=token
```

After getting access token, I try to get user's followers by sending a GET request to this link:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/201199350/follows?access_token={The access token i've got from the previous step}
```

For my account (which is the account the application registered with) it works perfect.

But the problem occurs when I try to get the 'follows' from other account.
I get 'Bad request 400' error.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

This is unsolved issue because `error 400` means, that user `not allowed` or `not found` (deleted by spam/bot system). Also you cannot get `followers` of private user, if an authentication user is not `follower` of him.

For the authentication users from first link you can use `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token={The access token i've got from the previous step}` link.